# DLE удаление пользователей

Tags: php, dle

DLE удаление пользователей, может кто реализовывал, после прохождение времени пользователь переноситься в другую группу, но хотелось бы чтобы он удалялся. Не кто не реализовывал такое?

Comment: Нашел, спасибо, решение в engine\init.php 323 строка в DLE 9.2, вдруг кому пригодиться.

Comment: Видимо, здесь не кто не пользуется DLE